# What get copied over when exec() is called?

Tags: process, operating-system, fork, exec

Let say we entered `wget` command. My understanding is that shell calls `fork()` and a child process is created. At this moment before `exec()` is called, the child process is identical to the parent process except for things like process ID.

Then when `exec()` is called, kernel replaces the child process' image with `wget`'s.

But environment variable is not overwritten, so I am confused what are replaced and what are retained from the parent process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my humble attempt to answer your question. However, I am afraid that the answer can be too overwhelming.

**Effect of exec() on process attributes**

[image]

Also, do visit [execve](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) man page.

Comment: Wow! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is entirely system specific. For a eunuchs system, there is going to be some area of memory set aside that is not going to be remapped upon exec (). On Linux, I believe this area is at the high end of the user address space.